# Distribution of difference knowing characteristic function.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Assume $X$, $Y$ independent random variables with the same distribution $\mu$ and characteristic function $\phi$. What can one deduce about the distribution of $X-Y$?

Comment: You may need to comment on whether they are independent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the independence of $X$ and $Y,$ you can easily calculate the C.F. for $X-Y.$ Now for a specific $\mu,$ $X-Y$ might follow a specific distribution. For instance, if $X,Y$ are iid Normal (resp. Cauchy) then $X-Y$ will also be Normal (resp. Cauchy), with different parameters.

If you are looking for properties then again certain properties can be derived from the C.F. of $X-Y.$ For instance, it's distribution will be symmetric around $0,$ no matter what $\mu$ is.

Comment: So as a matter of fact, X has the same distribution as Y and assuming they are real,  -X has the same distribution as X, but I cannot write that X - Y has the same distribution as X - X, because that would be the 0 random variable.

Comment: X having same distribution as Y does not imply that X - Y has the same distribution as X - X. Here you can use both the independence and identical distribution to *prove that* X - Y has the same distribution as Y - X, implying that their common distribution is symmetric about 0.